# How do I create a multi bar chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

this is a [bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219) here is the [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSmkHsUpW4JRnqArp6nE?p=preview) 
this is a [multi line series chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) here is the [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/sImexHz0GztMLGEOtJsC?p=preview)

How do I create a multi bar chart, building from the  multi line series chart example and bar chart example given above. So basically I just want to turn the multi line series chart into a multi bar series chart.

I think this is the code I have identified that I need to change:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });
```

My attempt so far is: I was hoping there would be a bar function instead of line, but the best I can find is area and this does not make a difference. [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/sImexHz0GztMLGEOtJsC?p=preview)

```
var bar_chart = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });


  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return bar_chart(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });
```

Another attempt**[#2]** is to try and write this in such a way that it draws the multi bar chart.

```
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

---

### EDIT1

Building on my attempt 2 above I added the following code. This at least draws a bar for me. Now I just have to work out how to do it per the dataset.
[PLUNKER here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/sImexHz0GztMLGEOtJsC?p=preview)

```
  city.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar3")
        .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return d.name})
        .attr("x", function(d) { console.log(d); return 19; })
        .attr("width", 158)
        .attr("y", function(d) { console.log(d.value); return 360; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return 90; });
```

---

### EDIT2

my attempt at swapping the values in the x axis to the lengend and vice versa. https://plnkr.co/edit/MFP1MK3ePGnwi6PvC9V4?p=preview 
Some more playing just me trying to understand it better my playing with it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/MFP1MK3ePGnwi6PvC9V4?p=preview

Comment: Check if this is useful to your requirement...https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: tks, wonder how i could not find that...

Comment: this is a [PLUNKET](https://plnkr.co/edit/MFP1MK3ePGnwi6PvC9V4?p=preview) but the example @Srikanth is the revers of what I want. In the example I want the x-axis values in the legend and the values in the legend on the x-axis...hmmm.